# Bootstrap typeahead AJAX call fail

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the type-ahead feature from bootstrap to populate a search bar dropdown using an AJAX call.

I saw some posts about it, but the best answer didn't solve my issue.

I get a `TypeError: a is undefined` from jquery.min.js (v1.8.1) each time I tap or erase one new letter in the input.

I am using the bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.1.1.

HTML:

```
<input class="input-xlarge" id="search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
```

JS:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
  source: function (typeahead, query) {
     return $.get('http://mywebsite.com/search', { query: query }, function(data){
     return typeahead.process(data);
   });
 }
});
```

Target:

```
    function search()
    {
      echo  json_encode(array('toto', 'tata', 'word'));
    }
```

I don't understand how this function can crash my jQuery lib.

Comment: it is not the function that "crash" jquery, but most certainly the data it receives, eg the output from "mywebsite".

Comment: It's just a json encoded array, i have update my sample to show it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){


            $('#search').typeahead({

                source: function (query, process) {
                    return $.getJSON(
                        'http://mywebsite.com/search',
                        { query: query },
                        function (data) {
                            return process(data);
                        });
                }

            });         

        });
```

and the json out put should be like this

```
[
    "toto",
    "tata",
    "word"
]
```

and html should be

```
<input name="sometext" type="text" class="input-large" id="search"  placeholder="type something">
```